# Usemin with hbs files

Tags: gruntjs, handlebars.js, grunt-usemin

Is there a way you can use grunts `grunt-usemin` with `.hbs` files. I only know how to use it for html files. But it would be ideal if it works for hbs files.

If any on you know of a solution, please let me know. I will be more than greatful!

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I actually solved this problem by setting up a layout.src.hbs file and having grunt generate a layout.hbs file for dev or production based on the environment. So it would minify and uglify in production, but not in dev.